# How do I scale the font of every element with a given class realitive to its parents dimensions using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my first responsive website and I've ran into some issues.

In Particular, I need some text to be centered, but when I try different window sizes with Responsive Design mode in FireFox Dev Edition, text that is centered wont really fit its container properly. So, I figured that JavaScript would probably be the best course of action.

While this works for elements selected with `document.getElementById('id');`, I can't seem to get it to work with classes by using a `for` loop.

Heres the code I use for elements with an ID:

```js
document.getElementById('header-text').style.fontSize = ((19/47.73) * document.getElementById('header-title').getBoundingClientRect().height).toString().concat('px');
```

Heres what I've tried to use with elements using a common CLASS.

```js
var allIconLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('extras-iconlink-text');
var i;
for ( i = 0; i > allIconLinks.length; i++ ) {
    allIconLinks[i].style.fontSize = (19.2/42.43) * allIconLinks[i].parentElement.getBoundingClientRect().height.toString().concat('px');
}
```

Its worth noting that nothing is executed inside the for loop at all, I tried to use a `console.log` function and nothing logged.

If its helpful, here is the HTML & CSS of the elements (I dont have  shown in this snippet but I do have `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />`):

```html
<body>
 <div id = 'header'>
  <div id = 'header-title'>
   <span id = 'header-icons'>
    <img id = 'icon-layer1' src = '../../assets/logos/layer1.svg'>
    <img id = 'icon-layer2' src = '../../assets/logos/layer2.svg'>
   </span>
   <span id = 'header-text'>Karakaras Portfolio</span>
  </div>
   <div id = 'header-extras'>
    <span id = 'extras-info' class = 'extras-iconlink'>
     <img id = 'icon-info' src = '../../assets/icons/info.svg'>
     <span class = 'extras-iconlink-text'>About</span>
    </span>
    <span id = 'extras-projects' class = 'extras-iconlink'>
     <img id = 'icon-info' src = '../../assets/icons/projects.svg'>
     <span class = 'extras-iconlink-text'>Dev projects</span>
    </span>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

```css
#header {
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 7.5%;
 background-color: #7161ef;
 position: fixed;
}
#header #header-title {
 top: 5%;
 left: 0.15%;
 width: 20%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
}
#header #header-title #header-text {
 display: flex;
 top: 5%;
 left: 25%;
 width: 80%;
 height: 90%;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: inherit;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: 'comfortaabold';
 font-size: 120%;
}
#header #header-extras {
 top: 5%;
 left: 22.65%;
 width: 77.25%;
 height: 90%;
 background-color: transparent;
 position: absolute;
}
#header #header-extras .extras-iconlink {
 display: inline-block;
 top: 10%;
 width: 4%;
 height: 80%;
 background-color: inherit;
 position: absolute;
}
#header #header-extras .extras-iconlink .extras-iconlink-text {
 display: flex;
 top: 0%;
 left: 100%;
 width: 250%;
 height: 100%;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: inherit;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position: absolute;
 font-family: 'comfortaabold';
 font-size: 120%;
}
```

I'm sure the mistake im making is super dumb and obvious, I don't really do Web Development a lot, I mostly do gamedev with Lua.

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't need to use JavaScript to center things. This is mostly a presentation problem well handled by CSS. I recommend you to go to these two links and see what you could use in every case depending in what exactly you need to center. Is not a long read.

[text-align](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-align/)

[Centering in CSS: A complete guide](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: I suppose its worth mentioning that the issue was mostly the font not scaling with the size of the window, not that it wasn't centered- god I feel stupid because I titled this thread completely wrong.

Comment: You may want to use REM units for your font sizes. They are relative to the default from most web browsers or the HTML element font size that you can change and that would be reflected in all rem units in your html page. By default 1rem equals 16px, 2rem is 32px, etc. Yo can use REM units in more elements, not just fon sizes too. Try it.

More about REM's
[There’s more to the CSS rem unit than font sizing][1]

  [1]: https://css-tricks.com/theres-more-to-the-css-rem-unit-than-font-sizing/

Comment: Question is: **How do I scale the font of every element with a given class relative to its parents dimensions using JavaScript?**
If you want to change a single value to affect all your fonts and some element sizes, I recommend to set your dimensions, fonts and elements in REM's and set your JavaScript code to change the HTML font-size. By default it would be 16px = 1rem. I'm just clarifying my previous answer based on your question changed. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the size of the font depending on the window size.
For example to set the font size of 20px on all screens below 600px you would use this CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
#header {
    font-size: 20px;
}}
```